Attempted to perform an unauthorised operation
I am running into this above-mentioned error, when trying to use "Get-WinEvent" command. I am running PowerShell ISE with elevated privileges, but unsure why it isn't working.
Would appreciate any help.
    # Get the filtered events
$events = Get-WinEvent -LogName $logName -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=$($eventIds -join ' or EventID=')]]"

> Get-WinEvent : Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
At line:16 char:11
+ $events = Get-WinEvent -LogName $logName -FilterXPath "*[System[Event ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-WinEvent], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWinEventCommand

Screenshot of the script and the error message

Pretty sure it goes wrong somewhere in your syntax. try to see if just get-winevents work with the minimum required parameters

Are you sure you have permission on this machine to read the events? Can you see then from Event Viewer signed on as the same user that executes the command? Does running powershell as administrator and then running it make any difference?
